# Auto Adjust Excel Chart Line Weights With a Loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I am trying to adjust the line thickness (or weights) on an Excel chart.  I want each line to adjust in thickness based on a weight I have saved in a named range "Weights"

I am having trouble getting this double loop right

I have the vollowing VBA loop, but at present it adjusts each chart serries to all every value in my "Weights" series, then carries on looping to the next Srs. I want each value in my Srs to change only once, then select the next weight.

When I try to force the loop onto the next "Srs" I get the 'Invalid next control variable reference'

How does this double loop need to be constructed to adjust each line (Srs) to each of my weights (£w)

Thanks

```html
Sub SetWeights()
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim myWeight As Range
    Dim £w As Range
    
    Set myWeight = Range("Weights")
 
    
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Srs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
             For Each £w In myWeight
             Srs.Format.Line.Weight = £w
      'Debug.Print £w
    Next 'Srs
        
        
    Next '£w
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub SetWeights()
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim myWeight As Range
    Dim £w As Range
    Dim j As Long

    Set myWeight = Range("Weights")

    j = 1

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each £w In myWeight
            If j > ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count Then Exit Sub
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Format.Line.Weight = £w
            j = j + 1
        Next £w
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Nailed it. Thanks!